# insert into using pyodbc lib in python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc within Python to import a few values into my SQL server DB.

```
for data_form in data['matches']:
    connprod = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:*****.database.windows.net,1433;Database=League_Stats;Uid=******;Pwd=******;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
    cursorprod = connprod.cursor() 
    lane= str(data_form['lane'])
    gameId= str(data_form['gameId'])
    champion= int(data_form['champion'])
    platformId= str(data_form['platformId'])
    timestamp= str(data_form['timestamp'])
    queue= str(data_form['queue'])
    role= str(data_form['role'])
    season= str(data_form['season'])


UPDATE_SQL = """\
    INSERT INTO MATCH_HISTORY_LIST
        (lane, gameId, champion, platformId, timestamp, queue, role, season)
    VALUES
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)
"""

print '--------------'
print "INSERT INTO Match_History_List(lane, gameId, champion, platformId, timestamp, queue, role, season) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)", lane,gameId,champion,platformId,timestamp,queue,role,season
cursorprod.execute(UPDATE_SQL, (lane,gameId,champion,platformId,timestamp,queue,role,season))
cnxn.commit()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rybau\Desktop\Parse Json.py", line 60, in <module>
    cursorprod.execute(UPDATE_SQL, (lane,gameId,champion,platformId,timestamp,queue,role,season))
ProgrammingError: ('42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

I have no idea where the `)` is coming from. I've tried just printing the statement and manually running it against the DB and it works successfully.

Comment: Remove the last comma from the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Thank you Dan! I can't believe I missed this.